# Firebase authWithOAuthToken not working

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-app, github-api, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase in my Google Chrome App.  Since Chrome Apps do not have a domain and a callback url, I need to authorize with the Token and not the popup.

I am having problems getting **authWithOAuthToken** to work, even in the browser.

In this code example the first call to **authWithOAuthPopup** works, I get the popupData which includes github account info and my token.  The issue is that the second call to **authWithOAuthToken** is not working.  I get an error

```
     db.authWithOAuthPopup("github", function(error, popupData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {

            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload: ", popupData);
            console.log("Now attempting to Authorize with Token...");


            db.authWithOAuthToken("github", popupData.token, function (err, tokenData) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Login Failed!", err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Authenticated successfully", tokenData);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My console output shows the first call working, and the second call failing:

```
  bundle.js:20498 Authenticated successfully with payload:  Object  
  Now attempting to Authorize with Token...
  Login Failed! Error: Invalid authentication credentials provided.(…)
```

How can I get **authWithOAuthToken** to work?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why would this ever be necessary? Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: This reduced test case executes an authWithOAuthoPopup successfully and receives a token from that callback.  However, if I try to use that token in authWithOAuthToken I get an error.  

I only need authWithOAuthToken to work because I am going to make that call from a Chrome App.  However, I have never seen it work.  I cannot get it working even in the browser... even after I receive a successful token... as demonstrated in this example.

I am hoping that the error is reproducible with this code...  One call working, and the second call failing.  How can I make the second auth call work too?

Comment: So you're unit testing the Firebase API; the third party library? Or attempting to test the generated token from Facebook? Both seem like superfluous tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token you would pass into `authWithOAuthToken()` needs to be a GitHub OAuth token, not a Firebase one. Thus the correct token would be `popupData.github.accessToken` rather than `popupData.token`. More can be read on the [token contents here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/github.html#section-logging-in).